# Problem With Conditional Statements

Tags: php, conditional-statements, if-statement

Every time I run this code, only `"Not from a"` gets written, whether the location is "a" or not.

```
function logsIn($dir, $account, $balance) {
   $d    = date("D F d Y - h:i A");
   $file = fopen("logs/$dir.txt", "a");

   if ($_SESSION['pass'] == "123") {
      if ($api["Location"] != "a")
         fwrite($file, "<span style='color:#FF0000;text-align:center';>Not from a.</span>");
      else
         fwrite($file, "From a.");
   }
```

Comment: Check the value of each variable you use and compare its value to what you expected. Basic debugging.

Comment: `location` is "a" or `Location` is "a"?

Comment: I'd also recommend, by the way, that you get rid of that "God conditional" on `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a variable called `$api` in your function, but **that variable is not defined anywhere**.

So, `$api["Location"]` cannot have the value `'a'` -- which is why the you always get `"Not from a"`.

Note : If you have a `$api` variable that's defined outside of your function, then, it is not visible from inside that function.

For more information about this, you should take a look at the [**Variable scope**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section of the manual.

As a solution, I suppose you could modify your code so :

- `$api` is expected as a parameter by your `logsIn()` function,
- And it is passed to that function when you call it.

You could also make the `$api` variable *(if it exists outside of your function)* visible from inside the function, using the [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword -- but it's not good practice, as it makes your function dependant on an external variable.